# Magento 1.5.0.1 Occasional 'Call to a member function getId() on a non-object'

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am using Magento 1.5.0.1 and am getting the occasional 'Call to a member function getId() on a non-object' error on checkout.

The customer will try several times to checkout with the same details and the error 'Call to a member function getId() on a non-object' will keep coming up, but then, after a few seconds or a few minutes, the error will stop and the checkout will go through.

This does not happen 100% of the time.

I have checked:
1) Apache error logs are clean, apache has lots of system resources free. Optimised for Magento according to official guide.
2) MySQL error logs are clean, mysql has lots of system resources free. Optimised for Magento according to official guide.
3) PHP error logs will only show 'Call to a member function getId() on a non-object', there is no indication that PHP ran out of ram, i.e. a failed to allocated memory error typical of RAM running out.
4) All other Magento optimisations have been performed: caching, compilation, APC, PHP limit of 256mb.
5) APC has lots of system resources fee.
6) CPU never maxed out 25-50% utilisation, RAM only 40-50% used, over 50% free!

Can also get 'Call to a member function getStoreId() on a non-object' error message.

I am tearing my hair out trying what else more I can do! Out of 50 orders, it will screw up for about 2-3 orders, i.e. the customer tries to checkout about 5-10 times in a space of 5-10 minutes.

What can be locking up?

Comment: What is the full error message? It should indicate while file/line the error came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I analyzed similar errors on my Magento install (1.4.2), I was able to put together that it was some kind of hack attempt against the site based on whois & nslookup searches. People (bots?) are placing orders without their session properly initialized, thus there isn't a store (or any other) object established for an Id to come from. This should be flagged as a bug so they can properly handle this case and re-initialize the session or perform some other action to better harden against people poking around the forms' logic.

Additionally, there is some kind of bug in the code where occasionally, a customer can place an order for an item that's $0. In every case, it was a normal customer, who when called, was surprised and gave us the CC details for manual payment processing. Clearing cache and everything first thing every day helps with this.

Comment: Interesting. It will not be a hack attempt, as customers are actually contacting us when it occurs telling us they cannot checkout. Also, something interesting to note: when this is occurring, when I myself try to checkout, I get the same problem. So the issue would not be isolated to a single user session. It just keeps happening again and again, where we have a period of 10-20-30 minutes where any attempts to checkout results in the error. There was a massive failure a few weeks ago when the error would not go away at all! I had to go into the database and reset the increment numbers.

Comment: It would not be the case of $0 items being added, because as described above, when the issue is occurring, I actually try to checkout myself and I can assure that the item is not $0. Also, during the outage where the the getId() error would not stop after hours, i did everything: 1) cleared all the caches, 2) reindex 3) cleared APC, 4) repaired the database... everything! The only that stopped it was when I reset the increment count in the magento database. But this doesn't explain why there are times where it will occur and go away after a few minutes, and the time when it did not go away.

Comment: BTW, the error is occurring on the onepagecontroller file, we have mods in our file so the line number will not be the same (and no the mods would not be causing this and they are extensions to do other stuff). We actually did a test, after the order is saved with ->save(); in the controller, the error occurs when getId() is being called and also when that was commented out, it stilled occurred when getIncrementId() is being called. ALSO interestingly, the order was NOT created. SO maybe the issue is not with getId() or getIncrementId(), maybe the object cannot be called because...

Comment: the order is not actually being created and saved in the first place, but if that is the case, what is causing the order not to be saved? we are not getting any other error message.

Comment: BTW, during these times, we are unable to create order, invoices, credit memos, shipping, basically anything to do with orders. It all stops. Quotes can still be created.